# how to center a title in mat card?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, styles

after I make my matcard size height to 10px, the title is out of position and it's not located right in the middle of the card anymore. I tried to use position and top in the css but nothing work. any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.

```
    <mat-card class="alert" *ngIf="showBroadcast">
      <mat-card-title *ngFor="let help of broadcastText | async">
          <p style="font-size: 15px; color: black; top: 194px;">{{getMessage(help)}}</p>
      </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card>
```

```
.alert{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color:  #D2232B;
  border-radius: 6px;
  opacity: 1; 
  height: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Display container as `flex` and align items center:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-nm6ywr?file=src/app/app.component.css

```
.alert{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color:  #D2232B;
  border-radius: 6px;
  opacity: 1; 
  height: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```